# Google Mini proxystylesheet

Tags: stylesheet, google-search-appliance

Current Google Mini setup uses customized stylesheet setup on the appliance. I am looking to apply a different style to another collection I am integrating into a site. How can I override the default and apply a custom style? Where do you place the custom stylesheet so that it can be referenced?

Answer (score 3):

The stylesheet used by your search results is determined by the "proxystylesheet" param.
You can create different front ends under serving -> front ends.
Ther you´ll be able to upload a new stylesheet or create different ones using the wizard .

Chack the docs on:
http://code.google.com/apis/searchappliance/documentation/50/admin_searchexp/ce_understanding.html#h1tools

Hope this helps,

Pablo